# How can I prevent my list item to disappear after page reload Mvc asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really new to MVC and C#
I modified the _Layout.cshtml to have a menu and on click of any menu item I have a jquery function to create sub menu items based on the parent that I clicked. When I click on any link in the sub menu It reloads the master page and clears my sub menu which is something I don't like. Can someone help me recreate dynamically the same sub menu after page reload or any idea to fix that issue is welcome 
OK
I created a controller that I am accessing in my _Layout to create my menu bar

```
 public abstract class MainController : Controller
    {
        private static HRMenuDataContext db = new HRMenuDataContext();
        public static string theVal, toCheck;
        public static int num;
        public static HRMenuDataContext theData
        {
            get { return db; }
        }

        public MainController()
       {
           //ViewData["Parent"] = from c in theData.psHCMLanguages
           //                     where
           //                         (from m in theData.psHCMMenus
           //                          where
           //                             m.sModule == "AP"
           //                          select m.sMainRef
           //                         ).Distinct().Contains(c.szCode)

           //                     select c;

           ViewData["parent"] = theData.theParent("HR");

           ViewData["check"] = theData.doCheck(toCheck);

           ViewData["Child"] = from c in theData.psHCMLanguages
                               where
                                   (from m in theData.psHCMMenu_1s
                                    let parent = theVal
                                    where
                                      m.sModule == "HR" &&
                                      m.sSubRef == parent
                                    select
                                        m.sPrompt
                                    ).Contains(c.szCode)

                               select c; 

        }
    }
```

in my _Layout.cshtml I have this

```
@using Menus.Data;
@using Menus.Controllers;
@using System.Linq;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Persol Systems</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/theStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #theSide {
            clear:both;
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            left:100px;
            bottom:50px;
            top:0;
            border:1px solid red;
            width:150px;
            height:600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @{
        string[] name;
        char[] sep = { ' ', '/', '\\', '.' };
        string mess="";
     }
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menux">
                        @{
                            foreach (var c in (IEnumerable<theParentResult>)ViewData["parent"])
                            {

                            <li><a>@c.English </a>
                                @{MainController.theVal = c.szCode;}

                                <ul class="firstChild">
                                    @{foreach (var d in (IEnumerable<psHCMLanguage>)ViewData["Child"])
                                      {
                                          var data = MainController.theData.doCheck(d.szCode);

                                          if ((int)data == 1)
                                         {  
                                             <li><a onclick="theAlert('@d.szCode','@d.English')">@d.English</a>
                                            @{
                                              MainController.theVal = d.szCode;
                                            }

                                         </li>  
                                          }

                                          else if (data == 0)
                                          {
                                              name = d.English.Split(sep);
                                              foreach (string nams in name)
                                              {
                                                  mess += nams;
                                              }
                                            <li>
                                                <a onclick="theAlert('@d.szCode','@d.English')">@d.English</a>
                                                @*@Html.ActionLink(d.English, mess, c.English)*@

                                            </li>
                                              mess = "";
                                              Array.Clear(name, 0, name.Length);
                                          }
                                      }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="body">  
        <div id="theSide">
            <ul id="sidePanel">

            </ul>
        </div>
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                  @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Persol Systems</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function theAlert(theId, theName) {
            $("ul#sidePanel").contents().remove();
            $("ul#sidePanel ").append("<li id='" + theId + "'><a >" + theId + "</a></li>");
            $("li#" + theId + "> a").click(function (e) {
                window.location.href("../Home/About");
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

on click of the link It reloads the entire page and clears my sidePanel

Comment: Please, provide some code...

Comment: i believe this has nothing to do with mvc or C#. are you trying to keep the dropdown visible after the page reload?

Comment: The page *mustn't* reload at all: that's a lot of wasted bandwidth. You need to generate divs appropriately, and never ever navigate away. Some code is needed for further details.

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point. He's using Javascript to generate a menu structure in the browser which he wants to preserve when he navigates.

Comment: I think he's saying that when people follow links around, the submenu doesn't stay open. I dont think he's talking about ajax.

Comment: I want that page to still be visible after navigating to another page

Comment: I.e. he wants to persist the state of the menu between page reloads

Comment: why not use a frame-like master page layout with a menu and a dynamically loaded content?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless which means any data that you do not persist will get lost between postbacks. If you want to persist that information you will need to use Javascript to send the menu structure to the server through Ajax or use browser based [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage).

Comment: Thanks will research on that and try I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

An example scenerio

model

```
public class Menu
{
    // prop parent for example 
    public List<Parents> parents{ get; set; }
    // prop child
    public List<Childs> child{ get; set; }
    // prop check
    public bool checked { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public class Menu: Controller
{
    public ActionResult _MainMenu()
    {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.Parent = // parent elements from your db context
        menu.Child = // child elements from your db context
        menu.Parent = // check element from your db context

        return PartialView(menu);
    }
}
```

_MainMenu.cshtml

```
@model Menu

// same like your layout view, fill here like layout
// for example
@foreach(var parent in Model.Parents)
{
    // generate menus
    ....
 }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
...
<nav>
    <ul id="menux">
         @Html.Action("_MainMenu", "Menu")
    </ul>
</nav>
...
```

I suggest you an example code you should modify Data Types that you want.

Comment: I am creating the sub menu on a click event using JQuery and it is on the click of any of the sub menu items the page is reloading and removing my sub menu as well because I believe it is not created on page load. I am creating it that way because on the click of any menu item it removing the content of the ul containing the sub menu before appending a new sub menu based on the parent clicked